# If $A,B$ are positive definite matrix then I need to prove so is $ABA^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A,B$ are positive definite matrix then I need to prove so is $ABA^*$, here is what I have done

$$x^*ABA^*x=(A^*x)^*B(A^*x)=y^*By>0$$, is it okay? $y=A^*x$

Comment: Well you need to add that every $y$ can be expressed as $A^*x$ for some $x$ which comes from the fact $A$ is positive definite and therefore invertible.

Comment: Why do you need that? You only need that $y$ is non zero; that comes from invertibility of $A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's almost ok. You should mention that $y = A^*x$ cannot be $0$ for $x \ne 0$, as $A$ is invertible. Moreover your computation shows that $A > 0$ isn't necessary, $A$ invertible suffices for $ABA^*$ being positive definite for positive definite $B$.

Comment: Actually, $\mathbf A$ doesn't even need to be square; it just needs to have full rank.

Comment: so for positive definite I used to know we need $x^TAX>0$ why you people hav used the definition $x^*Ax>0$?